# Make inline-blocks stretch container horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to make it so if the inline blocks inside a container exceed the width of the container they make it stretch rather than dropping down below.

I made a codepen of what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJQWbR

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content{
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Trying to make the blue boxes all be on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
white-space: nowrap
```

to the `container`

So container style becomes:

```
.container{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

> white-space: nowrap means  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text
>   will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a < br > tag is encountered

See the link : "http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGQXRz"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Just change the width of `.content` class.

```css
.container{
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content{
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```